# Query + httpRequests = many promises not working properly

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest

I have a simple code: there's a query and inside this query, for each item, Im making one httpRequest and this requests save data in 
My problem is: how to have all promises/requests/saves done before finishing the cloud-code.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Readers);
query.find({
    success: function(readersList) {
        for(var qi = 0; qi < readersList.length; qi++) {
            promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                url: '......',
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
                    var resultList = httpResponse.data.data.items;
                    for(var hRi = resultList.length; hRi > 0 ; hRi--) {
                        post.save();
                    }
                }
            }));
            break;
        }
        Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(){
            response.success("All Readers Done!");
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Mode detailed code:

```
query.find().then(functions(results) {

    var promises = [];

    for(var ri = results.length; ri > 0 ; ri--) {

        var promise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: results[ri]
        }).then(function (httpResponse) {
            var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
            var resultList = httpResponse.data.data.items;
            var savePromises = [];
            for(var hRi = resultList.length; hRi > 0 ; hRi--) {
                // not sure what "post" is in this context?
                savePromises.push(post.save());
                savePromises.push(results[ri].save());

            }
            // wait for all saves to finish
            return Parse.Promise.when(savePromises);
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    }

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

}).then(function() {
    //success
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT 2**
My intention is to: after a query, iterate in those elements and for each of them make an HTTP request to a feed. With the result of this feed I will check if the item already exists in the database and then save/update the items.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you're adding the `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()` promise to the array, but nothing is waiting for the `post.save()`. You can chain that to get the desired result:

```
var promise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: '....'
}).then(function (httpResponse) {
    var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
    var resultList = httpResponse.data.data.items;
    var savePromises = [];
    for(var hRi = resultList.length; hRi > 0 ; hRi--) {
        // not sure what "post" is in this context?
        savePromises.push(post.save());
    }
    // wait for all saves to finish
    return Parse.Promise.when(savePromises);
});
promises.push(promise);
```

Comment: I added the code you shared, and seem that it didn't work. It seems I need to make the code go sync so the success is called last. Anything called after the success will be ignored, at least it seems...